# Improve defineClass() performance for repeated multiple calls to load Java classes from byte code

Tags: java

I have a need to load Java classes dynamically from the supplied byte code repeatedly, lots and lots of times. This seems to be a fast operation, and I have managed to get the speed down to around 1 millisecond or less But I am noticing that the performance can be environment-specific (for example it depends on the choice of the Garbage Collector) and with busy multi-threading, the performance can deteriorate to 5MS or more, which is a big hit for my use-case.

I need to run this on Java-8 on Ubuntu or similar Linux. So far the best improvement to performance has been the switch to Parallel GC from CMS. I wonder if there is anything else I can do to improve the performance, particularly under busy multi-threaded scenario?

The simplified code looks something like this:

```
public class ClassTest  extends ClassLoader
{
    private String CLASS_NAME = "ClassName";
    private String METHOD_NAME = "MethodName";
    
    public Object loadAndExecute(byte byteCode[], Integer param1, Integer param2)
    {
        try
        {
            Class<?> fungCustomExec = defineClass(CLASS_NAME, byteCode, 0, byteCode.length);        
            Method m = fungCustomExec.getMethod(METHOD_NAME, param1.getClass(), param2.getClass());
            return m.invoke(fungCustomExec.newInstance(), param1, param2);
        }
        catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
                | InstantiationException | NoClassDefFoundError e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Just to add: the most demanding calls seem to be to `defineClass()` and to `.getMethod()` in the code above, whereas .invoke() seems to be OK.

Comment: Consider using MethodHandles instead of reflection.

Comment: Surely the bytecode can't be different for every call if 5ms is a performance bottleneck right? I would assume it's way more likely that you're using the same bytecode over and over in some kind of loop. If so, can't you cache the result so that the same bytecode doesn't get processed multiple times?

Comment: Given that you're micro-optimizing, it seems pointless to do `param1.getClass(), param2.getClass()` when you know that they're integers. Remove the method call completely and just use `Integer.class, Integer.class`

Comment: True, but I'm testing the stress-case scenario, where I need to assume that byte code can't be the same.

Comment: On your second point @Michael, you are right -- in practice I'm doing it once in the constructor, but I wrote it here like that just to simplify. But i guess you are right, Integer.class would be even better. Thanks!

Comment: @VS_FF Optimizing for the worst-case is fine, but a cache will massively improve your average case, so you should do both.